# How to access dark theme setting without AppCompat android q

Tags: android, react-native, android-10.0

I'm building an app in react-native that switches themes from light to dark. I'd like to have an option where it defaults to whatever the os has set, since currently it requires you to toggle it manually. I know there are ways to get other settings, but the only way of changing themes or even seeing what system setting is active was through the AppCompat as far as I could tell.

Comment: Currently there doesn't appear to be a way, but there is a github issue tracking it: https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/issues/126